# Composer install fails with bus error: 10

Tags: php, macos, composer-php, homebrew

I'm trying to install composer with:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

This fails with the error message:

```
Bus error: 10
```

I also tried

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

which gives the same error.

I'm on OSX 10.10.3 and PHP 5.6 installed with homebrew.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That was a nasty one. I actually checked all sorts of things until I discovered that xdebug forces ***all*** php scripts to stop in PhpStorm debugger.

Disablling the debugger in PhpStorm obviously solved the problem.

Comment: Wow, you saved me quite a few (more) gray hairs with that one!  Many thanks!

Comment: As of 2021 I think this is not the case anymore. My PhpStorm was also closed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it started to happen after switching back to PHP 5.6 to test a project.
So my `php -v` in the terminal shows I was using php 5.6, and composer would be also using this version.

I am using [valet-plus](https://github.com/weprovide/valet-plus/), and after switching versions everything crashed.
All I had to do was rolling back the php version manually.

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin
$ rm php   (which was a symbolic link to my valet php 5.6)
$ ln -s ../Cellar/valet-php@7.3/7.3.19_1/bin/php php
```

After that I could update my valet-plus and use php 5.6 in this project with no composer errors (after a `valet fix`, of course)