# composer dump-autoload return 'bus error (core dumped)'

Tags: laravel, composer-php, autoload, dump

'composer dump-autoload' command return 'bus error (core dumped)'
And it did not dump autoload file from vendor.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciw6w.png)
I used laravel framework on ubuntu os.
Can anyone help me?.

Comment: Sounds like an OS error, try `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. If that doesn't work, re-install composer.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700081/composer-install-fails-with-bus-error-10 help?

Answer (score 0):

Just run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Its a problem related with Linux/Ubuntu, not composer. If the problem persists, run a tool like `memtest` and check all it's ok. Also, check your filesystem and underlying device.